# Calling method Asyncronously from aspx

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asynchronous

i am using .net4.0 framework
i am working on Web Project using c#
i want to make some request which will populate some items in cache beforehand.

Ex.
user comes to the home page of application.
[ i will write some code in Home Page(.ASPX) which will call some method which will read some files from disk and put them into cache though i don't need this cache on home page... at this point as reading files from disk is going to be somewhat lengthy operation... i would to load home page completely without waiting for response from method(which is going to read files from disk)]
Something like

```
function page_load{

CacheGenerator.CreateCache();//this is going to be heavy operation..i don't want                           to wait for this operation to complete
repose.write("Hello world:); // this statement should run moment after above function is called
}
```

and one more thing can we do this without using threading.

Answer (score 0):

Anything asynchronous is "using threading" in one way or another.

More importantly, you should not start any async operation from a page. The page only exists in memory for the duration of the request. Your async operation may complete after the page no longer exists in memory.

You may be able to use the `Task` class to start an async operation from the Application_Start event in global.asax.

Comment: ya you are right page may not exist in memory... i going to do cache population[which i don't need on this page] code in method called from aspx. i was thinking this as something like calling WCF one way service is it possible